# Mac User, Running Mamp, Issues trying to modify files, inside root Folder (EACCES: permission denied) VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was wondering if there is an option or perhaps in near future, if we are able to input administrator password (sudo) within the program to be able to override the files or be able to open files inside mamp server or any lock folder.

I can't create files either within this folder, unless I use the terminal, but that its kinda of pointless, since i am really loving this ide and would like to stay a little bit away from terminals for a few.

Even after using

```
touch
```

to create files, the file would come out on the ide but i still wont be able to edit/save it.

Comment: Currently not supported, but please add this as feature suggestion to our user voice channel: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code

Comment: thanks appreciated, Please people vote! :)

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/8915236-visual-code-w-terminal-integrated-and-super-admin